# Is it possible to get the name of the user who triggered another Jenkins job through a static link?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job, ABC. The job runs every 24 hours as defined in the crontab. A build description is set after each successful build. The description is basically a link that triggers another job, XYZ.

[image]

Is it somehow possible to know which user clicked the link and triggered the job XYZ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to click in the **status** option of your job :

[image]

Comment: Hey @JRichardsz,

Thanks for the reply. This is something that wouldn't help when working with a link that triggers another job or else I would have definitely done this before itself.

What I get in the job XYZ's status tab is the host IP "Started by remote host 10.1.2.3".

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Aalap. Can you give an screenshot?  Also , how is performed your job? Some user click on a link and this opens a jenkins job? If this is true, a login is required, so user must be recorded by jenkins